# Is it possible to do horizontal mouseWheel scrolling with java.awt.Robot?

Tags: java, scroll, mouse, awt, mousewheel

I can use mouseWheel() from java.awt.Robot to simulate a vertical mouse wheel scroll.  On OS X I have a Mighty Mouse that will scroll horizontally too.  Is there any way I can simulate this with java.awt.Robot?  The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) only shows vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Not according to that framework.

But an alternative to this, and keep in mine I haven't done this in your environment, is if you are able to generalize the keystroke of the left and right scroll. You can essentially issue you application to move right and left. You can implement a keylistener that does that tick. This is how I have done a few of these for web application using JS.